# Problem with python urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm getting an error when ever I try to pull down a web page with urllib.urlopen. I've disabled windows firewall and my AV so its not that. I can access the pages in my browser. I even reinstalled python to rule out it being a broken urllib. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
>>> import urllib
>>> h = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    h = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 344, in open_http
    h.endheaders()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
    self._send_output()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 735, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 716, in connect
    self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\socket.py", line 514, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
>>>
```

Comment: works for me, probably you overloaded google with requests and they cut you off for a while

Comment: no its happening with any url I try to load.

Comment: oh, hmm. No proxy or something, or weird port voodoo in your firewall?

Comment: well, I turned off my software firewall. And my router cant be blocking it because I can access pages from my browser. What do you mean by proxy? is there somewhere  proxy can be set in pythons configuration or something?

Comment: Are you using Linux? Try running strace python yourscript.pl and see what you get.

Comment: I'm in windows but I have straceNT. I just don't really know how to read it ;/

Comment: here's a paste of where it died: 
http://www.pastie.org/968265

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[this could be the case](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17035#p79455):

> Just found the problem I had set a
>   proxy through internet options, that
>   proxy went offline, and so did my
>   python shell.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Apparently Idle uses the proxy settings from internet options. Thanks a lot Mykhal

Answer (score 0):

urllib is working just fine.

Try using ethereal (or some similar network sniffer) on your box to determine if the denial coming from your machine or a machine beyond.

Comment: It can't be a machine beyond, my browser can access the websites I'm trying. And its happening with every single website I try so its not some useragent problem or anything similar.